# How to change AKS node count via PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster used for development purposes. As such, I would like to implement an automation procedure so that the max node count will be decreased at EOD. For that, I created this PowerShell script:

```
 Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $Cluster.Name | Set-AzAksCluster -NodeCount 5
```

The above snippet is based on the example provided in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.aks/set-azakscluster?view=azps-6.0.0).

However, when I run this script I am getting the following error:

> You must specify one existing Node pool name to 'NodeName' for updating Node pool properties

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common issue. The documentation is exactly right when it releases at the beginning. But when time passed, the documentation does not update at the right time while the command updates. You see the command is `Set-AzAksCluster`, but the example still uses the command as `Set-AzAks`.

So I recommend you use the command like this:

```
Set-AzAksCluster -NodeCount 5 -NodeName $nodeName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $Cluster.Name
```

Comment: Thank you Charles Xu, your explanation is probably right: I've applied your proposal and the error message was gone.   However, this did not yield the expected result.  I ended up achieving my goal by using the following command instead:  
`Update-AzAksNodePool -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ClusterName $Cluster.Name -Name $NodePoolName -MaxCount 1`

Comment: @AviNehama Well, the set command only sets the configuration of the aks cluster. I just show you in which format it will work as you asked in the question. Of course, the update command  is necessary